# Index for a dynamic Kind in appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Currently my indexes are configured in a index.yaml file. But, how am I going to configure an index if the name of my Kind is created dynamically?

Thanks.

Comment: The short answer is don't do that. It's almost certainly the wrong way to use the AppEngine datastore. If you give more information about what you are trying to accomplish with a dynamic Kind we might be able to suggest a better way.

Comment: Is it a bad a idea because there is an index limit (this part I am not sure)? What I was trying to do is to create a dynamic kind separating product information that I thought will be modified frequently. This way I can have cheaper write operations, but I wanted to query them in descending order using the \_\_key\_\_, this way I can have them sorted by uploaded date in descending order.

Comment: I dont understand why you need a dynamic type to separate product info. Designing a database where collections may change during runtime is definitely a no-no due to overhead of indexing. I also don't think Go App Engine SDK has an interface to setup custom indexes.

Comment: I just needed to save write operations. If there were such, the overhead will happen just once. Anyways, it seems it cannot be with appengine for now. I can find other ways. Thanks.

Comment: Ahh, i think I am using the wrong word that adds confusion -- it is not dynamic that means the kind changes. The kind name is created at runtime once and when it is created, its name will not change anymore. :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean you need to create index dynamically on run time. But as far as I know the only way to do so is via index.yaml and appcfg.py

So probably you need to setup another server which have the GAE SDK installed, also with Apache and say (php). What you do is when that another server receives a HTTP request (called from your app in GAE), it generates a new index.yaml automatically and execute appcfg.py in command line.